# Several errors with InterpolatingFunction

Tags: differential-equations, list-manipulation, interpolation

I'm getting some error messages that don't make sense. Apologies, as the code is somewhat complex. Basically what I'm trying to do is solve a system of differential equations, then fill a table with values for time and ρsol21[time], with a few other things going on. This is done via a Do loop.

```
h2 = {{0, -(Ω/2)}, {-(Ω/2), -k v + Δ}}

ρ2 = {{ρ11[t], ρ12[t]}, {ρ21[t], ρ22[t]}}

ρtderiv := -I (h2.ρ2 - ρ2.h2) + {{1/2 γ ρ22[t], -γ ρ12[t]}, {-γ ρ21[t], -(1/2) γ ρ22[t]}}

replace3 = {Δ -> 10, γ -> 1, Ω -> 10, m -> 10^-25, ℏ -> 1.0545718*10^-34, k -> (2 N[Pi, 10])/10^-9};

txvarray = Table[{0, 0, 0}, 200];

t0 = 0; ρ120 = 0; ρ210 = 0; ρ220 = 0; ρ110 = 1; δ0 = (2 N[Pi, 10])/10^-10;

Do[ 
 {ρsol11, ρsol12, ρsol21, ρsol22} = 
  NDSolveValue[{ρ11'[t] == ρtderiv[[1, 1]], ρ12'[t] == ρtderiv[[1, 2]], ρ21'[t] == ρtderiv[[2, 1]], ρ22'[t] == ρtderiv[[2, 2]], ρ11[t0] == ρ110, ρ12[t0] == ρ120, ρ21[t0] == ρ210, ρ22[t0] == ρ220} /. replace3, {ρ11, ρ12, ρ21, ρ22}, {t, t0, t0 + 0.01}]; 
 t0 += 0.01;
 δ0 -= 0.01*(2 Ω^2 k^2 ℏ Im[ρsol21[t0]/Ω]/m /. replace3);
 txvarray[[i, 1]] = t0;
 txvarray[[i, 2]] = 2 Ω^2 k^2 ℏ Im[ρsol21[t0]/Ω]/m /. replace3;
 txvarray[[i, 3]] = δ0;
 ρ120 = ρsol12[t0];
 ρ210 = ρsol21[t0];
 ρ220 = ρsol22[t0];
 ρ110 = ρsol11[t0],
 {i, 1, 200}]
```

I'm getting a few error messages that I don't quite understand. The first is

```
NDSolveValue::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == 0.26002828028276154`.
```

And I don't have any idea what that means. The second is

```
InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0.27} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
```

This doesn't make sense because when t0=0.27, the domain for the NDSolveValue of that iteration is {0.27,0.28}, so 0.27 should be in the range data. The third message is

```
An unknown box name (ToBoxes) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression.
```

and I have no idea what this means either. Thanks for your time.

Comment: EDIT: I have identified the source of the third error. It is the line that goes δ0 -= 0.01*(2 Ω^2 k^2 ℏ Im[ρsol21[t0]/Ω]/m /. replace3);

Comment: The error message shows that (one of) the integrations stopped at `t == 0.26..`, which is less than `0.27`.  That means the interpolating function returned a domain also had a domain that stopped at 0.26+, so that in the update steps, `ρ120 = ρsol12[t0]`, which occurs after `t0 = 0.26` is incremented `t0 += 0.01` to `t0 = 0.27`, the input is not in the domain.

Comment: @MichaelE2 why would this happen at t=0.26? In theory the range data should be updated with each iteration so that this never happens, and it doesn't for the first 25 iterations.

Comment: The message says it's because "Maximum number of 10000 steps reached".  That can happen because of stiffness, a singularity, or a high number of oscillations.  You can plot the 26th solution to see what happened.

Comment: You didn't specify `v`, so the problem cannot be reproduced and investigated by others.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, this is the working code. There are no mistakes, it is necessary only to define one parameter and avoid numerical divergence. All this is achieved if we put `v=10^-9`. Then we get a beautiful picture on the output

```
h2 = {{0, -(Ω/2)}, {-(Ω/2), -k*v + Δ}};

ρ2 = {{ρ11[t], ρ12[t]}, {ρ21[t], ρ22[t]}};

ρtderiv = 
  -I*(h2.ρ2 - ρ2.h2) + {{1/2*γ*ρ22[t], -γ*ρ12[t]}, {-γ*ρ21[t], -(1/2)*γ*ρ22[t]}};

replace3 = 
  {Δ -> 10, γ -> 1, Ω -> 10, m -> 10^-25, ℏ -> 1.0545718*10^-34, 
   k -> (2 N[Pi, 10])/10^-9, v -> 10^-9};

txvarray = Table[{0, 0, 0}, 200];

t0 = 0; ρ120 = 0; ρ210 = 0; ρ220 = 0; ρ110 = 1; δ0 = 2*Pi/10^-10;

Do[
  {ρsol11, ρsol12, ρsol21, ρsol22} = 
    NDSolveValue[
      {ρ11'[t] == ρtderiv[[1, 1]], ρ12'[t] == ρtderiv[[1, 2]], 
       ρ21'[t] == ρtderiv[[2, 1]], ρ22'[t] == ρtderiv[[2, 2]], 
       ρ11[t0] == ρ110, ρ12[t0] == ρ120, ρ21[t0] == ρ210, 
       ρ22[t0] == ρ220} /. 
         replace3, {ρ11, ρ12, ρ21, ρ22}, 
      {t, t0, t0 + 0.01}, 
      MaxSteps -> Infinity];
  t0 += 0.01;
  δ0 -= 0.01*(2 Ω^2 k^2 ℏ Im[ρsol21[t0]/Ω]/m /. replace3);
  txvarray[[i, 1]] = t0;
  txvarray[[i, 2]] = 2 Ω^2 k^2 ℏ Im[ρsol21[t0]/Ω]/m /. replace3;
  txvarray[[i, 3]] = δ0;
  ρ120 = ρsol12[t0];
  ρ210 = ρsol21[t0];
  ρ220 = ρsol22[t0];
  ρ110 = ρsol11[t0], {i, 1, 200}]

txabs = Table[{txvarray[[i, 1]], Abs[txvarray[[i, 2]]]}, {i, 1, 200}];
ListPlot[txabs, PlotStyle -> Orange]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: I see this got an upvote, but I'm having trouble understanding how this solves the OP's problem.  Instead of solving the problem the OP wants to solve (for which `v` has not been given), your advice seems to be to solve a different problem with a different `v` chosen to let the integration reach `t == 2` (presumably your `v` is different since the OP's integration fails just past `t = 0.26`).  Is that right?

Comment: Maybe we can just ask the author to give us the secret value of the parameter $v$ at which he received the message and why he did not use the option `MaxSteps -> Infinity` and did not investigate the problem of stability?